# Подключение к серваку

Tags: windows, linux

На работе локальная сеть (WS 2003). Доступ к инту и все такое. Как можно из дома подключиться к нему? По IP пинг не проходит. Может есть другие варианты?

Answer (score 2):

а IP случайно не локальный? Если сервер не имеет публичного айпи или нужный для подключения порт не "проброшен" через роутер/фаервол, то без вмешательства в локальную сеть - никак.
Если хотя бы к одной машине в локальной сети, которая имеет доступ к серверу, есть доступ, то можно установить [hamachi](https://secure.logmein.com/products/hamachi/) и получить свою маленькую локальную сеть. Можно конечно установить хамачи и на сервер, тогда к нему будет легко достучаться, но это уже не совсем безопасно.

Comment: Или настроить себе VPN-тоннель в сеть.